# App Store - are "legal contract" kind of apps permitted?

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program, app-store-connect

I'm considering involving a lawyer in creating a simple app to create a contract between two people. They read and sign the contract on an iPhone and both get copies of it.

I know there are medical apps like WebMD that provide medical info, while disclaiming intent to diagnose, cute or treat conditions. Can the same approach be applied to an app that creates contract while disclaiming offering legal advise?

I'm interested if the kind of app I'm proposing would be allowed on the App Store?

Comment: I'm reading that as "I''m not a lawyer, or even if I am, then probably not one qualified in your country, therefore I can't claim that this contract is even vaguely sound in any jurisdiction on Earth, yet by clicking this you agree to abide by it"... I'm not sure you'd get many takers :/

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't be allowed. [There could be something else that prevents it from being accepted on the App Store, but assuming it gets reviewed and accepted, I see nothing that **Apple** would protest about.](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/) That said, there might be other legal issues, but that's not the point of this forum.

Comment: I'm not going to close this now - but how is this not a developer customer support question? See [Why we're not customer support](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) for general guidance. In this case - what section of Apple's review guidelines do you think you might be violating? How would we know Apple's thinking on how app review may or may not change by the time you get your app submitted? What's the budget of the app development?

Comment: I realized this is not a kind of question for StackOverflow, so I hoped it might be more relevant here. I will reach out to the app review team for more info and would update the answers with their advice.

Comment: It's quite relevant here. SO really doesn't want any Apple Service questions from what I can tell. We don't like code questions here - but this is about the service Apple provides which is explicitly on topic. Perhaps the close vote is due to feeling it's soft or unresearched. I felt the question was good enough to merit thinking about a response. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has made it abundantly clear that they will reject apps for reasons that change over time.

1. The review guidelines explicitly say - your app will be rejected if it's too similar to many other apps. So - the first person to do this might breeze through review. The 10th or 50th, not so much.
2. The review guidelines and nature of thousands of apps means that not all reviews are equivalent - what one app does to get through might be rejected for weeks or months as you work with Apple to meet the review you get. Different teams and different people will make different decisions no matter how well intentioned a company is to make reviews uniform and fair to all.
3. iOS apps of the category of remote notarization are now live (several versions of that app exist), many real estate and digital signature verification / electronic contracting services exist (this is far more crowded a slot than notary) and all manner of business apps are booming on the app store as the premium and pay to play gaming juggernaut gets so saturated that apps with real functionality will hopefully become more prevalent.

Thus, setting aside any notion that you can "read the tea leaves" based on what apps have been approved in the past, it's probably a "first mover" advantage and don't invest more than you can afford to lose until you have something you can submit and then work through your specific review feedback with Apple as opposed to guessing what may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Only Apple's review staff can answer this question.** Any answer offered here can only be an opinion.

As the Apple's App Store guidelines stand today, the app may be accepted. However, Apple reserves the right to reject apps that carve new niches and push boundaries.

## Contact Apple

Talk to Apple's App Store staff about how best to approach your app and how to avoid being rejected:

> #### App Review
>
> Find out the status of your app and [submit general questions](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) for the App Review Team.